# Overloading Operators in C++ with a Template

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operators, overloading

I've a problem with Operator overloading in C++.

I've defined the following class:

```
template <class T>
class Array
{
public:
//! Default constructor
Array(int ArraySize = 10);

////! Defualt destructor
Array<T>::~Array();

//! Redefinition of the subscript operator
T& Array<T>::operator[] (int index);

//! Redefinition of the assignment operator
const Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(const Array<T>&);

//! Redefinition of the unary operator -
Array<T>& operator-(Array<T>& a);

//! Array length
int size;

private:
//! Array pointer
T *ptr;
};
```

The unary operator - is defined as follow:

```
//! Redefinition of the unary operator -
template<class T> 
 Array<T>& operator-(Array<T>& a){
    static Array<T> myNewArray(a.size);

    for( int i = 0; i < a.size; i++){
    myNewArray[i]=-a[i];    
    }
    return myNewArray;
}
```

How can I avoid the persistence in memory of "myNewArray"? Whitout "static" declaration
myNewArray disappears when the function ends and fails any assignment like VectorA=-VectorB.

The second problem is about the overload of casting operator; I've overloaded the casting operator this way:

```
//!CASTING
template <class B>
operator Array<B>(){
    static Array<B> myNewArray(size);

.... a function makes the conversion and returns myNewArray populated...

return myNewArray;
}
```

But it doesn't work! The object myNewArray seems to disappear after the function execution with the static declaration too. Any assignment like VectorA=(Array<'anytype'>)VectorB fails.

Where is the error? May everybody suggest a solution, please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the cast operator, again, no need for the `static`. Without actual code that compiles and runs and shows the problem, though, it's impossible to say what's going wrong.

Comment: Avoid cast operators as much as possible. It's hard to predict when implicit casts are triggered and this leads to hard to find bugs. You should consider making a templated assignment operator instead: `template <class B> Array& operator=(const Array<B>& rhs)`. This would allow you to explicitly convert an `Array<B>` into an `Array<T>`.

Comment: You could also write a templated explicit constructor that allows to explicitly contruct an `Array<T>` out of an `Array<B>`.

Comment: Your `operator-` is not unary. It operates on both `*this` and `a`. How can `VectorA = -VectorB` even compile? I suggest you try to make a small code example that actually compiles that you can show us -- it always helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you all! I've found the problem: it was the copy constructor. The by-value-return of functions and the command A=f(b) didn't work because the copy constructor was wrong. After rewriting it all works fine without static and by-reference-return.

Answer (score 1):

For your operators don't return a reference. Return a copy of myNewArray. Most compilers can elide the copy and use return value optimization to make performance acceptable.

You should also mark those methods as const as they do not change state.

```
template<class T> 
 Array<T> operator-(const Array<T>& a) {
    Array<T> myNewArray(a.size);

    for( int i = 0; i < a.size; i++){
    myNewArray[i]=-a[i];    
    }
    return myNewArray;
}
```

Comment: @Jupiter Oops, one character off.

Answer (score 0):

> Without "static" declaration myNewArray disappears when the function
>   ends and fails any assignment like VectorA=-VectorB.

No, it doesn't. The compiler makes sure it hangs around long enough to get copied.

Also, the code will be a bit cleaner if you initialize myNewArray as a copy of the original:

```
Array<T> myNewArray(a);
for (int i = 0; i < myNewArray.size(); ++i)
    myNewArray[i] *= -1;
```

Comment: Whoops, as @EthanSteinberg pointed out, since the function returns a reference, the `static` is needed. Better, though, to return **by value**.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, since both problems involve mysterious failures to properly assign new values, is there something wrong in the assignment operator?

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not an answer.